# How to disable automatic expression evaluation when break point in debug mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio Community 2019, I open a C# winform solution developed from Visual Studio 2010. It's working well, but in debug mode when it hits a break point, Visual Studio is automatically evaluating an expression and it's taking some time so I have to wait because the window is froze until the evaluation is done.
[image: debug screen]

I have checked the debug settings and I untick some options, but it doesn't change.
[image: debug settings screen]
Thanks for help

Comment: Try `Tools -> Options -> Debugging and unselect "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls"`.

Comment: Yes as shown in my debug settings screen it's unselected, but it's still evaluating the expression evene after relaunching visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution. My old project was with target framework .NET Framework 3.5, I just switch it to .NET Framework 4.7.2 and now no more slow microsoft visual studio evaluating expression 'x' ...

Answer (score 0):

I found another approach that might be useful in some cases: [DebuggerDisplay()].  Provide an alternate display that doesn't invoke the problematic code.

My problem was with lazy initialization--some reasonably expensive calculations were likely not to be used, but the debugger always used them.  A big problem when the bug is in the offending initialization code.  Now the debugger displays a null rather than executing the ??= part.